# HTC DESIRE 820, how would I go about rooting this phone?

Tags: rooting, htc-desire

I have this ***HTC desire 820*** and I would really like to *ROOT* this phone. The OS is getting a little long in the tooth and I would love to do something about this. I currently have an aversion towards windows and therefore I run **Debian Linux 9.whatever**. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks heaps.